# HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44343/api/nominate", ok: false, …}

Tags: c#, angular, api, .net-core

Getting Status 400 error. Thanks in advance.

**Component.ts**

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl1 + 'api/nominate', clsPostNom).subscribe(result => {
      alert(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

**.Net Core Controller** Not calling this method while checking with Breakpoint

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]clsPostNom obj)
{ 
      // Todo
      return Ok(true);
 }
```

**Console**

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the Controller. Please provide the entire .Net Controller.

Comment: NominateController.cs. Not calling the method and getting error.

Comment: The problem most likely lies with your route, instead of calling an endpoint that does not exists (which would return 404) it is calling a controller, but no method. Switch your URL to this: `this.baseUrl1 + 'api/nominate/post'`

Comment: 400 indicates a missing parameter or bad parameter in the request.  If you have an application that works with the server than use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the 1st request.  The default headers in c# are different from other applications.  Make the c# headers look like working application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]dynamic clsPostNom)
{   
 // Todo
 return Ok(true);
}
```